# Why is my getter returning null when the setter returns what its supposed to

Tags: java, getter-setter

My setter test value is the passed arguement.  When I try to get it in the getter method, it returns null.  I can not figure this out for the life of me.

Here is my full code.  I think it may be outside of the method issue.

```
package com.graphics.tyler;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JPasswordField txtPassword;
private JTextField txtUsername;
//private String email;
private String test;

public String getLoggedEmail() {
    System.out.println("Get logged email is: " + test);
    return this.test;
}

public void setLoggedEmail(String passedName) {
    System.out.println("Passed argument is: " + passedName);
    this.test = passedName;
    System.out.println("Setter Username is: " + test);
}





/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MainFrame() {

    Driver drive = new Driver();

    setTitle("Graphics project");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(300, 30, 800, 600);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblWelcomeToGraphics = new JLabel("Welcome to Graphics program");
    lblWelcomeToGraphics.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 27));
    lblWelcomeToGraphics.setBounds(208, 11, 360, 33);
    contentPane.add(lblWelcomeToGraphics);

    JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnExit.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            dispose();
        }
    });
    btnExit.setBounds(703, 11, 71, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnExit);

    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
    lblUsername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lblUsername.setBounds(60, 199, 97, 25);
    contentPane.add(lblUsername);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
    lblPassword.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lblPassword.setBounds(66, 281, 91, 25);
    contentPane.add(lblPassword);

    txtPassword = new JPasswordField();
    txtPassword.setBounds(159, 284, 193, 20);
    contentPane.add(txtPassword);

    txtUsername = new JTextField();
    txtUsername.setBounds(159, 205, 193, 20);
    contentPane.add(txtUsername);
    txtUsername.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblDontHaveAn = new JLabel("Dont have an account? Sign Up!");
    lblDontHaveAn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            UserCreation userCreate = new UserCreation();
            dispose();
            userCreate.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    lblDontHaveAn.setBounds(601, 536, 193, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblDontHaveAn);

    JButton btnSignIn = new JButton("Sign In!");
    btnSignIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String email = txtUsername.getText();
            String password = new String(txtPassword.getPassword());

            int password1 = password.hashCode();
            String password2 = Integer.toHexString(password1);

            if(drive.signIn(email, password2)) {

                System.out.println("Login Sucessful!");
                UserScreen nextScreen = null;
                setLoggedEmail(email);
                try {
                    nextScreen = new UserScreen();
                } catch (Exception e1) {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                nextScreen.setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Email or password is incorrect");
            }

        }
    });
    btnSignIn.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    btnSignIn.setBounds(208, 342, 97, 33);
    contentPane.add(btnSignIn);
}
}
```

This is the class where I call the getter method in:

```
public UserScreen() throws Exception {

    Driver drive = new Driver();
    MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();

    drive.getUserInfo(mainFrame.getLoggedEmail());
    System.out.println("User screen email is: " + mainFrame.getLoggedEmail());
```

Comment: You're probably calling it in the wrong order or on a different instance.

Comment: yep - code as shown don't see an issue so problem is in the code you aren't showing ;-)

Comment: Show a [mcve], please.

Comment: Show the whole class code. @TylerBull

Comment: did you call first setLoggedEmail before you call getLoggedEmail ?

Comment: and did you call it on the same object, or on a different object?

Comment: I dont call the get method until another class

Comment: where did you call getLoggedEmail ? I can't see it in the code.

Comment: Its in a different class @msagala

Comment: You've added a whole lot of code to the question, but you haven't shown the code where the methods are actually called.  That's where the problem is.  Not in what you've shown.  You may as well undo your edit.  All this extra code isn't really helping diagnose your problem.

Comment: so you need to pass getLoggedEmail in that class. you will not get what you set on this class because I assumed that you instantiate MainFrame in that anotherClass and you call getLoggedEmail. thats a different object you are calling.

Comment: I am pretty sure I called the setter method first because the output is:
Login Sucessful!
Passed argument is: tbtylerbull@gmail.com
Setter Username is: tbtylerbull@gmail.com
Get logged email is: null @msagala

Comment: I got it working by making the test variable static and the setter static.  Not to sure how that worked but it did.  Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments, so that everything is in one place. Comments without upvotes are normally not shown. Make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: @TylerBull Your problem was that you called the setter on one object, then the getter on a different object, which was probably NOT what you wanted to do.  But `static` means there's one copy of the variable shared between all the objects of that type - so you've fixed the symptom but not the underlying cause.  It's important that you understand this.  msagala's answer might help.  KPJAVA's answer won't.

Comment: This is where stepping through the code in your debugger should help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
public UserScreen() throws Exception {

    Driver drive = new Driver();
    MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame(); // You instantiate new MainFrame

    drive.getUserInfo(mainFrame.getLoggedEmail());
    System.out.println("User screen email is: " + mainFrame.getLoggedEmail());
```

You instantiate a new `MainFrame` thats why you get **null** on `mainFrame.getLoggedEmail()`.

you need to set the value in the same object you created. not the one you newly created.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are calling getter method first and then the setter.

see below code sample. This will execute and give correct result.

```
 String test;

 public static void main(String []args){
    HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld();
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    h.setLoggedEmail("HI");
    h.getLoggedEmail();
 }


public void setLoggedEmail(String passedName) {
    System.out.println("Passed argument is: " + passedName);
    this.test = passedName;
    System.out.println("Username is: " + test);
}


public String getLoggedEmail() {
    System.out.println("Get logged email is: " + test);
    return this.test;
}
```